# c# Query overlapping date

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I want to check if this specific room is already reserved:

```
bool overlaps = false;
```

This way only finds the ***first*** `roomId` with a value of `5` because it is `FirstOrDefault();`

```
var room = (from u in db.Reservation
             where u.RoomId == roomId
             select u  
           ).FirstOrDefault();

if((StartDateWantToBook <= room.EndDate) && (room.StartDate <= EndDateWantToBook))
{
     overlaps = true;
     MessageBox.Show("This room is already reserved");
}
else
{
   // Process to reserv this room
overlaps = false;
}
```

But If I have a `roomId` with value of 5 in multiple rows with different start and end date, I think I have to use `Tolist()` instead.
Maybe like this:

```
var room = (from u in db.Reservation
            where u.RoomId == roomId
            select u  
           ).Tolist();
```

**Question:**

How to check ***every*** `roomId` with value of 5 and then prevent overlapping dates in the same room?

I tried the following but sometimes it doesn't work...

```
foreach(var item in room)
{
  if((StartDateWantToBook <= item.EndDate) && (item.StartDate <= EndDateWantToBook))
  {
       overlaps = true;
       MessageBox.Show("This room is already reserved");
  }
  else
  {
      // Process to reserv this room
      overlaps = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please change your code for more readability

```
bool overlaps = false;
foreach(var item in room)
{
  if((StartDateWantToBook <= item.EndDate) && ( EndDateWantToBook >= item.StartDate))
     {
        overlaps = true;
        MessageBox.Show("This room is already reserved");
        // or you could use break; here to exist 
     }
}
// you could continue here by checking if(overlaps)
```

By using this , you could remove else block to reduce some coding lines.

Comment: thank you for your response, but where to continue if this room is not reserved? If it is not reserved the nI want to reserv it. So where to begin reservation?  Where to put reservation codes. What I Think is it's coming to continue after foreach and reserving the same Days in the same room. How to continue if not reserved then? Tha't why I tought I needed else block...

Comment: you see my comment ouside of foreach loop ?? you can check if(overlaps) and do the remaining procress . Right ??

Comment: I did it after foreach  if(!overlaps){MessageBox.Show("Hello")};  But there is no action. I can't get MessegeBox to show.

Comment: Thank you. I moved bool overlaps = false; inside my button function. It was in the begining av form. But now it's working perfekt

Answer (score 2):

The `else` block sets `overlaps` to `false`.  Even if there's an overlapping reservation, it gets set to `false` if the last one it processes doesn't overlap.  Get rid of the `else` block.

Comment: thank you for your response. Do you mean in FirstDefault() or Tolist()? And then How to process reservation then if not this room reserved? Isn't it in else block?

Comment: In the `foreach` loop.  Also, you can `break;` from the loop once you've found one that overlaps because finding any more non-overlapping reservations doesn't change the fact that you found one.

Comment: thank you again, but where to continue if this room is not reserved? Where t oput reservation codes. What Think is it's comin to continue after foreach and reserving the same Days in the same room. How to continue if not reserved then? Tha't why I tought I needed else block...